# AngularJS Append and compile in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem, i wish to append html elements in a directive in angularjs, and i wish to compile them for example i wish to append a {{ text }} and i wish to compile this with ~~~ $scope.text = "example...";

how can i do this?
is this possible? how?

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var matrixelement = document.getElementById("matrixcontent");

var app = angular.module('testviewer', ['ngMaterial', 'ngSanitize']).controller('matrixviewCtrl', matrixviewCtrl);


app.directive("matrixview",function($compile){
    return {
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            var svg = angular.element("<p>{{ text }}</p>");
            iElement.append($compile(svg)($scope));
        }            
    }
});



function matrixviewCtrl($scope, $compile) {


}
})();
```

Comment: you're doing it here `iElement.append($compile(svg)($scope));`, what's the problem?

Comment: Remove the dollar sign from the scope variable in the directive so it's `iElement.append($compile(svg)(scope));`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
iElement.append($compile(svg)($scope));
```

To this:

```
iElement.append($compile(svg)(scope));
```

Acutally you only have to remove the $ sign from scope because in your link fuction it is mentioned as `scope`.

Comment: Glad it helped you! You can up-vote & accept it if it did though ;)